# catch QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR on localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, local-storage

I'm using html5's localStorage API.

I want to catch the `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` so I can show a message to the user like "Memory is full. Cannot save. Maybe delete a few items?"

The code that I will use is like

```
function save() {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(key, name);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.name === 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR') {
            alert("Memory is full. Cannot save. Maybe delete a few items?");
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong? Try again later?")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ask you, is this ok? Will this work fine to all browsers? Will work fine or break, anyways?

Of course I am testing it too, but I thought I should ask anyways, because maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 10):

`e.name` for a quota exceeded error won't always necessarily be `"QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR"` in every browser.

It may be `"NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED"` in certain versions of FF http://chrisberkhout.com/blog/localstorage-errors/

May be `"QuotaExceededError"` or `"W3CException_DOM_QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR"` depending on IE browser version/mode [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197050(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, you are still catching the error. So worst case scenario is the user will get the "Something went wrong?" alert vs. the "Memory is full" alert.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use 'Disk storage' instead of 'Memory', because it is more clear. 'Memory' is more often stands for RAM, not persistent storage